# Display all record from table with perticular row at top

Tags: php, mysql

I want to display all record from table. ex. From Student table.
And particular student information on the first row.
ex. student id = 3 at top then display other student information.

```
So result look like 
Id  Name    City
3   PQR     xyz
1   LMN     xyz
2   ABC     xyz
4   WXY     xyz
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's generally better to fire two queries to do this and put the results together in your application.

However there are a couple of techniques that will work.

The two techniques I'd consider are:

**1. Use a Union**

```
SELECT * FROM students WHERE id = 3
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM students where id <> 3;
```

Or even

```
SELECT * FROM students WHERE id = 3 
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM students where id <> 3 order by id) x;
```

**2. A complex order by statement**

```
SELECT * FROM students order by id = 3 desc, d;
```

Be aware that this is easier to read, but arguably will have lower performance on large well indexed tables as it the optimizer will be unable to use the index for ordering.

Comment: I like the UNION approach, but this should really be UNION ALL.

Comment: You'll also need to give that second query's sub query an alias.

Answer (score 1):

```
select * from students
order by id <> 3,
         id
```

or

```
select * from students
order by case when id = 3 
              then 1
              else 2
         end,
         id
```

Answer (score 0):

I like:

```
  SELECT * 
    FROM student
ORDER BY id = 3 DESC, /* id = 3 returns 1 (true) or 0 (false) */
         id /* This will put your other students in ASC order of id */
```

Comment: Be aware that using this technique forces the optimizer away from using indexes for sort order since no index will have id=3 in its order.

Comment: I wasn't aware of the indexing problem, I was reading it like a WHERE clause.. thanks for the hint.